# Non-obvious restrictions in virtual servers

Tags: virtualization, swap

I apologize in advance for a beginner question.

What attributes should I check for besides the obvious CPU, RAM, storage and bandwith parameters when ordering a virtual server?

Two settings which have made a virtual server unusable after setting it up where:

1. numproc limit (they hat set 96, which prevented the server from beeing useful)
2. swap space (virtual machines managers like virtuozzo do not allow to configure 'user swap', which makes some software like Oracle DB impossible to install)

What other limitations can be relevant for a virtual server?

Comment: Virtuozzo/OpenVZ is really containers, not virtual machines. Most people looking for a VPS should avoid it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yes, that was the mistake I made. I thought OpenVZ is just like any other VPS. Could you post this as an answer?